# Why can Ansible AWX only have one machine credential per inventory?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

Is there a reason not to set credentials for each host?
When defined multiple hosts in one inventory, is it common sense to share one private key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for this, you can have separate creds for each host. But as per the best practices, you should keep separate user with a single key for host login and AWX  also user single login creds for all hosts login afaik.

Comment: I will consider adding new user for cred sharing. Thank you.